# using sub query in sql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 4 Tables:

```
Travelers (TravelerID,FirstName,LastName) 
Guides(GuideID,FirstName,LastName) 
Locations(LocationID,LocationName) 
Trips(TravelerID,GuideID,LocationID,Stars,StartDate,ReturnDate)
```

I want to return per guide the name of location which he guided the maximum number of travelers.the result needs to contain all the guides even if they didnt have travelers at all

I have tried to use this sub query but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT G.FirstName,L.LocationName,count(distinct(TravelerID))as 
number_of_travelers_per_guide 
FROM Guides AS G 
LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
GROUP BY G.FirstName,L.LocationName 
HAVING max((SELECT T1.number_of_travelers_per_guide 
        FROM Trips AS T1 
        WHERE T.GuideID=T1.GuideID));
```

the result should be like this:
[image]

I will appreciate any help

---

Edit by me [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner):

```
/* data creation script - python 3.6.2

import random

random.seed(815) # fixed 0815 seed

Travelers = [[x,'a' + str(x), 'A' + str(x)] for x in range(20)] 

Guides = [ [x,"guide_" + str(x), "G_" + str(x)] for x in range(10)]

Locations = [[x, "location_" + str(x)] for x in range(6)] 

# Trips(TravelerID,GuideID,LocationID,Stars,StartDate,ReturnDate)
Trips = []
for n in range(300):
    Trips.append([random.choice(range(20)),random.choice(range(10)),random.choice(range(6)),random.randint(1,6),None, None])


def prnList(lst):
    def prn(lst):
        for i in lst:
            yield " ,".join([str(x) for x in i]) + "\n"
        yield "\n\n" 
    return "".join(prn(lst))

with open("demodata.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Travelers\nTravelerID,FirstName,LastName\n")
    f.write(prnList(Travelers))
    f.write("Guides\nGuideID,FirstName,LastName\n") 
    f.write(prnList(Guides))
    f.write("Locations\nLocationID,LocationName\n") 
    f.write(prnList(Locations)) 
    f.write("Trips\nTravelerID,GuideID,LocationID,Stars,StartDate,ReturnDate\n")
    f.write(prnList(Trips))
*/
```

This data was cropped due to limitations in sqlfiddle length:

```
CREATE TABLE   Travelers     (`TravelerID` int, `FirstName` varchar(3), `LastName` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO   Travelers    (`TravelerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`)
VALUES
    (0, 'a0', 'A0'),
    (1, 'a1', 'A1'),
    (2, 'a2', 'A2'),
    (3, 'a3', 'A3'),
    (4, 'a4', 'A4'),
    (5, 'a5', 'A5'),
    (6, 'a6', 'A6'),
    (7, 'a7', 'A7'),
    (8, 'a8', 'A8'),
    (9, 'a9', 'A9'),
    (10, 'a10', 'A10'),
    (11, 'a11', 'A11'),
    (12, 'a12', 'A12'),
    (13, 'a13', 'A13'),
    (14, 'a14', 'A14'),
    (15, 'a15', 'A15'),
    (16, 'a16', 'A16'),
    (17, 'a17', 'A17'),
    (18, 'a18', 'A18'),
    (19, 'a19', 'A19')
;


CREATE TABLE Guides     (`GuideID` int, `FirstName` varchar(7), `LastName` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO Guides     (`GuideID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`)
VALUES
    (0, 'guide_0', 'G_0'),
    (1, 'guide_1', 'G_1'),
    (2, 'guide_2', 'G_2'),
    (3, 'guide_3', 'G_3'),
    (4, 'guide_4', 'G_4'),
    (5, 'guide_5', 'G_5'),
    (6, 'guide_6', 'G_6'),
    (7, 'guide_7', 'G_7'),
    (8, 'guide_8', 'G_8'),
    (9, 'guide_9', 'G_9')
;


CREATE TABLE Locations    (`LocationID` int, `LocationName` varchar(10));

INSERT INTO Locations    (`LocationID`, `LocationName`)
VALUES
    (0, 'location_0'),
    (1, 'location_1'),
    (2, 'location_2'),
    (3, 'location_3'),
    (4, 'location_4'),
    (5, 'location_5')
;


CREATE TABLE Trips    (`TravelerID` int, `GuideID` int, `LocationID` int, `Stars` int, `StartDate` varchar(4), `ReturnDate` varchar(4));

INSERT INTO Trips    (`TravelerID`, `GuideID`, `LocationID`, `Stars`, `StartDate`, `ReturnDate`)
VALUES
    (0, 4, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (9, 5, 3, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 9, 0, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 3, 2, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 0, 2, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (1, 4, 4, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 4, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 7, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 2, 1, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 6, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 8, 1, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 0, 1, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 8, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 3, 3, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (4, 8, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 5, 0, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (10, 9, 5, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 8, 0, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 7, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 4, 1, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 7, 5, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 9, 5, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (4, 5, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 1, 2, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 6, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 3, 0, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 0, 0, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (18, 6, 2, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (14, 4, 5, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 8, 1, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 1, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 1, 5, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 1, 4, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 5, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (14, 6, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 8, 3, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 1, 1, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 1, 0, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 4, 0, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 6, 5, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 8, 3, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 8, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 3, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 4, 4, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 8, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 1, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 4, 2, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 8, 0, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 8, 3, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 7, 1, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 4, 4, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 0, 2, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 5, 2, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (14, 8, 0, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 0, 1, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 7, 3, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 2, 0, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 0, 4, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (4, 6, 0, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 2, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (9, 6, 4, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (11, 1, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 5, 2, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (1, 5, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 6, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 4, 5, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 3, 5, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 5, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 2, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 0, 1, 4, 'None', 'None'), 
    (15, 3, 3, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 1, 5, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (14, 8, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 5, 4, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 1, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 8, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 4, 4, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 5, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 4, 5, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 8, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (10, 0, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 8, 0, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (9, 6, 5, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (9, 7, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (18, 2, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 9, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 5, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 4, 1, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 6, 4, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 9, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 3, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (13, 2, 3, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 8, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 8, 0, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 3, 2, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (11, 1, 2, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 1, 0, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 4, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (1, 5, 1, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 8, 4, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 5, 3, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 9, 4, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (1, 8, 2, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 9, 2, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 2, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 1, 2, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (6, 9, 1, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 1, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 1, 5, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 9, 1, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (3, 4, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (11, 6, 2, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (8, 0, 5, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (5, 1, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 3, 0, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 1, 2, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 6, 1, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 7, 4, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (2, 2, 4, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 2, 2, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (10, 4, 4, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 1, 1, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 2, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 5, 3, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (11, 3, 4, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (15, 1, 2, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (9, 4, 0, 3, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 3, 5, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 8, 4, 6, 'None', 'None'),
    (14, 5, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (19, 6, 3, 1, 'None', 'None'),
    (17, 5, 3, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (12, 7, 0, 5, 'None', 'None'),
    (7, 0, 1, 2, 'None', 'None'),
    (0, 1, 4, 4, 'None', 'None'),
    (16, 2, 0, 3, 'None', 'None')

;
```

Comment: I could swear I saw this same question 1-2 hours ago.  Did you repost under a different username?

Comment: i wrote this question again because the answer i got wasnt exactly what i was looking for. the person who helped me told me to write a new question

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i wrote the other questin but the answer i got there wasnt exactly what i was looking for @Patrick Artner

Comment: exactly @PatrickArtner the first answer didnt return a list of all the guides(even if they didnt have travelers)

Comment: @PartickArtner scaisedge asked linda to raise a new question on the back of linda's previous question so this is not a duplicate in my view.

Comment: @linda you are more likely to get a suitable answer if you include sample data as text in your question together with expected result.

Comment: i am not aloud to add photos of the result @P.Salmon

Comment: i really need help with this

Comment: Create sample data that is sufficient to illustrate what it is you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: i dont know how to do this

Comment: Linda, I added a python script and some DDL based on the generated data. Your task: _REVIEW IT_  ignore the missing dates - they are not important for your question so far. Could not be bothered to randomize those as well. If the data fits - someone might take it to create a superduper solution to your restricted abilities to use mysql features (no variables, etc.)

Comment: @P.Salmon retracted the flag. The idea of creating the same questions again without new informations reminds me of a proverb - "Doing the same thing over and over again, expecting different results is called insanity"

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the guide but first the guide with max number of teavelers you could use an order by desc eg:

```
  SELECT G.FirstName, L.LocationName, count(distinct(TravelerID))as number_of_travelers_per_guide 
  FROM Guides AS G 
  LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
  LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
  GROUP BY G.FirstName,L.LocationName 
  ORDER BY number_of_travelers_per_guide DESC
```

If you need  the max guide and alos the others  name then you could joj the result from the max with all the guides

```
select Guides.FirstName, my_t2.LocationName,  my_t2.number_of_travelers_per_guide 
from (

    SELECT G.GuideId, G.FirstName,L.LocationName, count(distinct T.TravelerID ) as number_of_travelers_per_guide 
    FROM Guides AS G 
    LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
    LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
    GROUP BY G.FirstName,L.LocationName 
    HAVING count(distinct TravelerID ) = ( 
                select max(my_count) from (SELECT count(distinct T.TravelerID) my_count
                FROM Guides AS G 
                LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
                LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
                GROUP BY G.FirstName, L.LocationName ) my_t )
  )  my_t2
left join Guides on Guides.GuideID = my_t2.GuideID
```

Comment: the code that you wrote doesn't return the location which the guide had the maximum number of travelers, its return all the location he guided and i want only one location (with the maximum travelers)

Comment: the previous code that you wrote was good  i just need it to return all the list of guides (including the guides that didnt have travelers at all)

Comment: i don't uderstand your question  .. you should update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  ,result ..

Comment: the code that you wrote me before was good but it returned only 2 guides from the list (including 7 guides) i want to return a table with guide first name, location name and amount of travelers he guided in this location. the returned location should be the location that this guide guided the maximum number of travelers.

Comment: I don't uderstand your comment  ..  .. you should update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected ,result . .. `just update the question with a proper data sample and the expected  result  `..

Comment: answer  updated ..  hope is what you are looking for otherwise  .. my suggestion are not useful for you  ..